# java dynamic class loading that avoids java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-loading

Oracle JavaDocs explains that IllegalAccessError is

> "Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field, or to
>   call a method that it does not have access to."

I try to load a class dynamically and I get this exception.

if I understand correctly when you use a classloader to load a class with a private package dynamically IllegalAccessError happens

the class I am trying to load is using

> org.xml.sax.helpers.SecuritySupport

which also states in their description in the following url
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.xmlcommons/com.springsource.org.apache.xmlcommons/1.3.4/org/xml/sax/helpers/SecuritySupport.java
that

> Unfortunately, we can't load the class using reflection
>          * because the class is package private.  And the class has
>          * to be package private so the APIs aren't exposed to other
>          * code that could use them to circumvent security.  Thus,
>          * we accept the risk that the direct reference might fail
>          * on some JDK 1.1 JVMs, even though we would never execute
>          * this code in such a case.  Sigh...

how can I dynamically load it anyway? I have to get it to work.
also if I get an error when I use a classloader, I cannot recover from that, so how can I know in advance that I cannot load this class?

thanks in advance to anyone who helps

Answer (score 2):

The statement “*we can't load the class using reflection because the class is package private*” doesn’t make any sense, as can be shown easily:

```
package somepackage;

class BaseClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        BaseClass obj=(BaseClass)
            Class.forName("somepackage.SubClass").newInstance();
        obj.aMethod();
    }

    void aMethod() {
        System.out.println("base class");
    }
}
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    void aMethod() {
        System.out.println("method overridden by subclass");
    }
}
```

This works flawlessly, printing `method overridden by subclass` replicated the actual use case of that `SecuritySupport` class.

However, since that class obviously serves the purpose of allowing a transition between Java 1.1 and Java 1.2, it might be possible that there were such restrictions twenty years ago, when this transition happened.

Your use case, however, is entirely different. You say that you are trying to load a class which “is using `org.xml.sax.helpers.SecuritySupport`”, which doesn’t imply that it is using said class via Reflection, but as shown above, that doesn’t matter anyway. It either case, it would only work, if the class is in the same package, whether you load the class “dynamically” or not.

There are only two possible scenarios.

1. If the class is truly within the same package, which at runtime implies that it also has been loaded by the same class loader, which would require that is also part of the JRE, if the JRE’s `org.xml.sax.helpers` package defines a `SecuritySupport` class, then the class *can* access the class within the same package.
2. If you are trying to load a class via a different `ClassLoader` from a different code source, it will not be of that package, even if you’d give it a qualified name of the `org.xml.sax.helpers.SomeClass` form. If the JRE’s `org.xml.sax.helpers` package happens to define a `SecuritySupport` class, all non-JRE classes would be in a different package. When it tries to access that class, which is not part of the official API, it doesn’t work.

   Note that all standard class loaders follow a delegation model trying to resolve a name through their parent class loader first, which is the reason why they all would prefer the JRE’s `org.xml.sax.helpers.SecuritySupport` class, if there is one. With non-standard class loaders, you could have different, unrelated classes with that qualified name, being in different runtime packages.

In that second scenario, the question arises, *why* your class is using that class. In 2017, there’s rarely a need to differentiate between Java 1.1 and Java 1.2 and the functionality offered by that class is also only relevant for a class *within* the privileged code source of the JRE (or different code sources with different privileges in general).

Comment: Since your example class above doesn't define a constructor, it creates a default constructor which (I think) is public by default. So when you call `newInstance` there isn't an IAE. With `SecuritySupport`, this likely isn't the case. Can you try adding a package private constructor and see if you can still can create a new instance? I'm guessing it won't work.

Comment: Actually, your main method (where you're creating a new instance of the class) resides in the same package as your example class, so of course your example works. Can you check if it works if your main class is in a different package from the class you're dynamically creating?

Comment: @Alvin Thompson: Both, `SecuritySupport` and `SecuritySupport12` *are* in the same package, that’s the whole point. So it is not clear why `SecuritySupport` contains a claim that it couldn’t load `SecuritySupport12` via Reflection. Don’t forget, that the consequence of the claim is that `SecuritySupport` loads and instantiates `SecuritySupport12` directly, without Reflection, which, of course, relies on being in the same package as well.

Comment: @Alvin Thompson: By the way, neither, `SecuritySupport` nor `SecuritySupport12` have an explicit constructor, not that it matters, as the compiler generated default constructor has the same access level as the class, so these non-`public` classes have non-`public` constructors too. But ironically, that package-private class doesn’t even exist in recent JRE’s, so when just using the official `org.xml.sax.helpers` API, you would never encounter it, not even behind the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, that's a mystery. However, let's back to the OP's question. When attempting to dynamically load his class, the class loader must first attempt to dynamically load `SecuritySupport`, since his class requires it.

Comment: In other words, I think the loader can't dynamically load SS because he's in a different package than SS.

Comment: ...if SS were linked at compile time, it would work.

Comment: ...I could be wrong but it seems to make sense based on my limited knowledge of how class loading and security work.

Comment: @Alvin Thompson: class loaders do not differentiate between “dynamic loading” and “non-dynamic loading”, they have only one way of loading. The linking happens at runtime, done by the JVM. If both, SS and the class using SS were defined by the same class loader and have matching qualified names before the last dot, they are in the same runtime package. But as said, it’s entirely unclear why the OP *needs* SS. It only encapsulates four trivial operation, `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`, `System.getProperty(propName)`, `new FileInputStream(file)`, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147748/discussion-between-alvin-thompson-and-holger).